# Does Firebase Storage support bundled uploads?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Considering Firebase Storage is simply a File storage CDN and does not have any special functionality for images (IE: Thumbnail generation) it is required that we generate these on the client.

The issue that I've come across a few times is that we're ending up with orphaned files, because a user will prepare to upload an image, and considering we have to upload the Original image and the thumbnail separately, the user may cancel the upload or exit the application.

If one of the images was already uploaded, and the other one was not, then there's an orphaned file sitting on storage that isn't being used anywhere, and the worst part is that it never will be.

Okay, so if the user manually cancels the upload we can check to see if the first upload was successful and if it was initiate a delete request. No big deal, but in the event of application exit, there's nothing we can do.

I'm hoping there is, or at-least soon will be, a way to upload a batch of files in an "All succeed or all failed" manner, similar to that of transactions in the Firebase Database.

How can I get around this problem? Do I just have to deal with orphaned files..? Is there any way to easily delete orphaned images in Firebase storage without downloading all of our users, generating a collection of links, and then downloading the links to all of the files on Firebase Storage, checking against the links and then initializing delete requests? Seems like a pretty heavy task.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is set a `complete` flag in a `user` when everything went fine, in the database, and keep this field indexed. If anything goes wrong before all tasks are finished (abortion, exit, crash...), the field will not be set.

Then, a basic housekeeping script would just check he user entries where this flag is `false`:

```
firebaseRef.child('users')
  .orderByChild('complete')
  .equalTo(false)
  .once('value')
  .then(ref => {
    // ref.val() -> contains all invalid users, check only them, fix/delete stuff, etc
  });
```

Also, you do not have to initiate a file download to check its existence, you can use `getDownloadUrl()` method:

```
storageRef.child("file.png").getDownloadURL()
  .then(() => {
    // The file exists
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // The file does not exists
  })
```

Full workflow details:

1. create user in database, with `complete` field to `false`
2. **after that** start all additional actions like uploading image, creating thumbnails, etc (no need to store anything that you dont need in the database at this point, like links)
3. **after and only after** update the `complete` field to `true`

About the UI: only display users with `complete` field set to `true`, to avoid broken display

Result: If anything crashes - *for any reason* - before step 3, the user field `complete` will stay at `false`.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that we're assuming that the link to the file would be stored in the user's object if the user exits the application. As the two images are completely relevant on eachother, they are saved such as: `{image: '...', thumbnail: '...'}` and once cannot exist without the other, or the UI of the application loading the object will break. Thus, we'd still have to check against every users links versus the available objects in the storage.

Comment: I'm not sure to follow you here. No need to store the file links, and any aborting/exit/crash is taken care of. I updated my answer to be clearer about the workflow I propose.

Comment: Even with the user field having `complete` set to true or false, this does not have any reference to the item that was uploaded into storage. If one item was uploaded, complete would be false, but how would we know which items to delete during the cron-job? Items in storage are named using `RFC 4122 UUIDs` as items with the same name can be over-written. Perhaps the issue is with the way I store data in Firebase storage. I have all of my user uploaded content in a single directory. Do you recommend a different file structure for this approach? Can't figure out how to decide on...

Comment: which images need to be removed from storage based on the `complete` function being false. The user may also have numerous photos, so I don't want to delete all of their photos, just the photo that was uploaded and orphaned. I say "orphaned" because when the upload is completed, the download link is added into a `photos: []` under the user node.

Comment: Ok I assumed it was a kind of profile picture in the user creation process, I don't know why (and was wrong :) ). Anyway the basic idea was to use a manual transaction mecanism to identify storage errors - with help of the database. Indeed ifwe talk about pure storage operations, you could pair that with a database operation. For example a `incompleteFileOps/xxx` tree where you  put an item when starting a file operation, and deleting that item only when it fully succeed. Then, check for timestamps older than, say, 1 hour, to fix/remove buggy storage items.

Comment: But yes storage-only operation would be difficult to troubleshoot if there is no way to identify them, by definition. File and DB structure are a big part of architecture !